# Sed Command get text between two string while excluding the two strings using Terminal UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal

So I have a sed command that looks like this:

```
sed -n "/DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/,/',sizingMethod='crop');/p"
/Users/ME/Documents/weather/yahooWeather.html > /Users/ME/Documents/weather/out.txt
```

And it correctly gets the HTML that I want out of the file, however it still has the strings that I used to search for it (i.e. "DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" & "',sizingMethod='crop');"  on the beginning and the end of the file. I'd like to remove those two strings. How can I modify my command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -n -e "1,/START/d" -e "/END/,$d" -e p file.html
```

I separated 3 commands there using the `-e` options but you could put them all together separated by `;`.

And this is what they do:

- `1,/START/d` -- deletes a range: from the first line of the file until the line matching the pattern `/START/`
- `/END/,$d` -- deletes a range: from the line matching the pattern until the end of the file
- `p` -- print the line (these are lines not matched by previous patterns)

**UPDATE**

If the pattern is on the first line, the above won't work. With GNU `sed`, you can fix that like this:

```
sed -n -e "0,/START/d" -e "/END/,$d" -e p file.html
```

Unfortunately this won't work with BSD `sed`.

Comment: I noticed that this breaks if the the first pattern is on the very first line. Using `0,/START/d` as the first command fixed that.